# TYPE_USE annotation in hibernate validator

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I know hibernate validator supports `TYPE_USE` annotations: though it does not define its own, it lets you define and use custom ones.

I could define and validate correctly such an annotation (code soon), but then I want to map the error into a path that is used to display the error to the user.

Given then following sample

```
public class SampleTest {

    private final Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

    public static class LimitedSizeStringValidator implements ConstraintValidator<LimitedSize, String> {

        private LimitedSize constraint;

        @Override
        public void initialize(LimitedSize constraintAnnotation) {
            this.constraint = constraintAnnotation;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            String s = Ensure.notNull(value);
            return s.length() >= constraint.min() &&
                s.length() <= constraint.max();
        }
    }

    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @Target({TYPE_USE})
    @Constraint(validatedBy = {LimitedSizeStringValidator.class})
    public @interface LimitedSize {

        String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}";

        Class<?>[] groups() default {};

        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

        int min() default 0;

        int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    private static class TestBean {
        @Valid
        private Collection<@LimitedSize(max = 3) String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        @Valid
        private Collection<InnerBean> beans = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private static class InnerBean {
        @Min(3)
        private final int value;

        private InnerBean(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testBeanInvalid() {

        TestBean testBean = new TestBean();

        assertThat(validator.validate(testBean)).isEmpty();

        testBean.strings.add("ok");
        testBean.strings.add("ok2");
        testBean.beans.add(new InnerBean(4));
        assertThat(validator.validate(testBean)).isEmpty();

        testBean.strings.add("not_ok");
        testBean.beans.add(new InnerBean(2));

        Set<ConstraintViolation<TestBean>> violations = validator.validate(testBean);
        assertThat(violations).hasSize(2);

        StreamSupport.stream(violations.spliterator(), false)
            .forEach(v -> {
                System.out.println(v.getPropertyPath());
                System.out.println(v.getMessage());
                v.getPropertyPath().forEach(p -> System.out.print("'" + p.getName() + (p.getIndex() != null ? "[" + p.getIndex() + "]" : "") + "' -> "));
                System.out.println();
            });
    }
}
```

I would like map the errors in an object like

```
errors: [
  ["beans", "1", "value"],
  ["strings", "2"]
]
```

As in my sample, my approach at the moment is by navigating the violation path (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html#getPropertyPath--) which works perfectly for the first case, but fails for the second (I cannot find a way to retrieve the index of the failing object). I think the reason is in the implementation of [javax.validation.Path.PropertyNode](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.1.Final/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/path/NodeImpl.java#NodeImpl.getIndex%28%29) in hibernate-validator (I am currently on version `5.2.4.Final`, and the code looks the same as in the linked `5.2.1.Final`. For reference:

```
@Override
public final Integer getIndex() {
    if ( parent == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return parent.index;
    }
}
```

With `TYPE_USE` this approach cannot work in my opinion, because the failing object is a leaf, thus no child node can retrieve the index from it.

Nice enough, hibernate implementation of `javax.validation.Path` overrides the `toString` method is way such that `violation.getPropertyPath().toString()` is `beans[1].value` and `strings[2]` (in the sample code above).

So, to the question(s): is my navigation approach wrong and there is another way to extract such a mapping from the `ConstraintViolation`? Or is this a feature request for hibernate developers (I can see that before `TYPE_USE` annotations the `getIndex` approach they implemented was totally fine?

It just feels strange I am the first one with this problem (I tried to google and could not find anything related, the closest being: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/pull/441) so I am wondering whether the mistake is mine rather than a hibernate limitation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the index should be set for that value and think you uncovered an issue in Hibernate Validator. Could you open an issue in our [JIRA tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HV/summary)?

Btw. the notion of TYPE_USE level constraints will be standardized as of Bean Validation 2.0. So there may be some more changes coming up in this area, specifically I'm wondering what `Kind` that node should have (currently it's `PROPERTY` which seems questionable).

Comment: thanks for the quick feedback. here the issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1121. I may even think of opening a PR directly myself (but not before Sunday for sure)

Comment: The issue has been fixed in Hibernate Validator 5.3.0.Final.